# Question about browsing the web using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I have got an arduino, a TFT touch screen and a WIFI module. The question is can i visit a specific web site and display it on that screen and interact with it.

Comment: no. you would need a html rendering engine like Gecko oe WebKit

Comment: yes, but you'd have to use an opera-mini style pre-render process on a middle-man.

Comment: As already pointed out in @Kwasmich's answer, you are vastly overestimating the capability of an arduino. Another more powerful board (Such as a Raspberri-PI) could possibly handle those tasks. But Arduino's + your Wifi module are much better suited for allowing remote monitoring and control of simple processes. The coding and hardware that go into displaying a web page with graphics may seem easy these days, but there are some mountains you'll need to climb to understand why its much harder than it seems. Don't let that discourage you though! Mountains can be climbed!

Answer (score 3):

You just have to install Chromium and call the desired page.

No, just kidding. I don't think you will ever fit a parsing and rendering engine on an arduino. Chromium for example takes about 150MiB of storage and depending on the opened page hundreds of MiB of RAM. Both of which is multiple orders of magnitude larger than the Arduino has to offer.

You might want to consider going to use a SBC like the Raspberry Pi for such usecase.

Alternatively you can query the data over network and write your own rendering code for the TFT display.